# Having problems with collection.remove on Meteor

Tags: meteor

I'm new to web development and to meteor.

I've come by a problem. 
I inserted some documents into a collection and am now trying to remove them but I can't succeed.

I used these lines to find/insert into a collection, they worked:

```
Cases.find();
Cases.insert({Case_Id:caseid, Product_type:prodtype, Machine_number:text});
```

Now, Im trying to remove a document (let's say one whose Case_Id = 12):

```
Template.main.events({
'click .rem_Case_But':function(){
    Cases.remove({Case_Id:12});
}});
```

It wouldn't make any change.

I've also logged into the minimongo and tried to remove them manually. Was successful.

Do you have any idea?

P.S. I didn't use any allow/deny options at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [remove section](http://docs.meteor.com/#remove) of the meteor docs:

> Untrusted code can only remove a single document at a time, specified by its _id.

"Untrusted code" means code executed on the client - so in your case you'd need to do:

```js
var c = Cases.findOne({Case_Id: 12});

if (c) {
  Cases.remove(c._id);
}
```